# Is the discrete root considered a hard problem?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, hardness-assumptions

I know that in groups from large prime order the discrete log problem is considered hard. For example, it is hard to compute $x$ from $g^x$ and $g$.

Does the same holds for the root problem? For example, is it hard in such groups to compute $g$ from $g^x$ and $x$?

Comment: Can you efficiently compute multiplicative inverses modulo a prime?

Comment: What's the definition of the $x$-th root?

Comment: Yes, I can. But how does it help me? The $x^\text{th}$ root of an element $h$ is some $g$ such that $g^x=h$.

Comment: Can you modify that equation so that you have $g$ on one side?

Comment: @Maeher I guess there is something pretty trivial including the multiplicative inverse of $h$, but I don't see it. I actually tried all these steps before asking...

Comment: Hint: there are several cases to consider. The group can have "hidden" (unknowable) order (e.g. $\mathbb Z_n^*$ with given $n$ of unknown and hard to obtain factorization), or the group can have known order $m$. And in the later case, we must consider the value of $\gcd(m,x)$, which determines if there exists $y$ with $x\,y\equiv1\pmod m$. Notice that with such $y$, it's pretty easy to solve for $g$ the equation $g^x=h$, answering the Q for that branch of possibilities.

Comment: @fgrieu-modelectiontime Note that the question specifies that the group has prime order.

Comment: @AmitKeinan taking the $x$-th root is the same as raising to a specific power. What is that power? Can you compute it?

Comment: @Maeher: Ah I have missed that. And I can't think of a hidden order group with prime order, plus the statement rather suggests a known order. So that's one less branch, leaving two.

Comment: @Maeher and fgrieu - thanks for the comments, but TBH I don't get you. It seems like stuff that are trivial to you are hard for me (and for other students in my class I showed them your responses). I would appreciate if you could answer the question. Also if you don't want to - thanks for the help!

Comment: $g^n = ?{}{}{}$

Comment: It should not have same complexity as we can easily calculate square roots and even cube roots using Tonelli-Shanks.  For large numbers I do not know currently.

Comment: I can only find one reference, see page number 394 of [Encyclopedia of Cryptography and Security](https://raphiinconcordia.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/encyclopedia-of-cryptography-and-security.pdf)

Comment: @kelalaka $g^n=g$. So if I will find a such that $a\cdot n=1 mod p$ then $(g^x)^a=g^{ax}=g^1=g$. I can find such a using the euclid's algorithm. Does it sound like a good direction?

Comment: Now, you are on the correct path.

Comment: thanks @kelalaka

Comment: You can write your answer, it is better...

Comment: @kelalaka done :)

Answer (score 2):

After the discussion in the comments, and with the help of @kelalaka I will answer myself.

I will assume that $p$, the order of the group $|G|$, is prime, and that $0 \neq x \in\mathbb{{Z}}_{p}$.

$p$ is prime, so we can efficiently compute the multiplicative inverse of $x$ modulu $p$, that is $a\in\mathbb{{Z}}_{p}$ such that $x\cdot a=1\;mod\;p$, using the extended Euclid's algorithm (*).

Then, we can raise $h:=g^x$ to the power of $a$ and get $h^{a}=(g^x)^{a}=g^{x \cdot a}=g^1=g$.

(*) How can it be done? Because $x$ and $p$ are coprime ($p$ is prime and $a\in\mathbb{{Z}}_{p}$), so the extended Euclid's algorithm finds integers $y,z\in\mathbb{{Z}}$ such that: $xy+pz=gcd(x,p)=1\;mod\;p$

Subtracting $pz$ from both sides we get:$xy=1\;mod\;p$, as we wanted.

Comment: Counterexamples to _"$p$ is prime, so we can efficiently compute the multiplicative inverse of $x$ modulo $p$"_ include $(p,x)=(7,21)$ and $(p,x)=(5,0)$.

Comment: @fgrieu-modelectiontime when was the last time you've been asked to take the zeroth root of something?

Comment: You're quite close, but still not correct.
Take for example, $g=2$, $x=5$, $p=13$. Then $g^x  = 6 \mod p$ and $a = x^{-1}  = 8 \mod p$.
However $g^{ax}=3 \mod p$.
You're looking for $x^{-1} \mod \varphi (x)$.

Comment: @limeeattack Thanks! Why mod $\phi(x)$? What is the rule for exponentiation $(a^b)^c$ mod p?

Comment: @limeeattack but exponentiation in $Z_p$ is actually multiplication, no? So your example is incorrect.

Comment: @AmitKeinan I meant $\varphi(p)$ not $\varphi(x)$. Sorry if that caused some confusion. You want to find the multiplicative inverse over the order of the group. So $g^{ax}$ reduces to $g^1$.

Comment: @limeeattack - but the order of the group is $p$, not $\phi(p)$.

Comment: The example of @limeeattack is in fact not a valid counterexample. $\mathbb{Z}_{13}^*$ is *not* a prime order group.